# How do I define a datatable so that List<String> fields will expand when mapped to datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataview

Seems the easiest looking problems are the hardest to solve.

I am writing some code to dump data from Amazon Web Services.  I collect the data and store it in a datatable.

```
    public static DataTable GetEC2DetailsTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        // Here we create a DataTable .
        table.Columns.Add("AccountID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("InstanceID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("SecurityGroups", typeof(List<string>));

        //This code ensures we croak if the InstanceID is not unique.  How to catch that?
        UniqueConstraint makeInstanceIDUnique =
            new UniqueConstraint(new DataColumn[] { table.Columns["InstanceID"] });
        table.Constraints.Add(makeInstanceIDUnique);

        //Can we set the view on this table to expand IEnumerables?
        DataView mydataview = table.DefaultView;

        //????Can we define the field here somehow?

        return table;
    }
```

In my program I have a function that fills one of these tables, and I would like to just dump it straight into a WPF DataGrid to display.  Below,  datable is returning my new datatable.

```
            var datable = Scanner.GetEC2Instances(ProfilesComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), RegionListcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
            DasGrid.ItemsSource = datable.DefaultView;
```

This works great, except for the columns where data is typeof List of strings.  For those columns, the data is just presented in the Datagrid as (Collection).

I have seen all kinds of examples where the XAML code is editted, but I would prefer to build the logic right into the datatable. I plan to be dumping other datatables to the grid so dont want to contaminate it.  In theory I should be able to edit the default TableView to make this work, shouldnt I?  Been all over the web trying to solve this.  The last hurdle before I can really start cutting loose.

Comment: how do you plan to display `List<string>` in your grid?

Comment: The easiest way is to flatten the `List<string>` to just `string` when you get the data. Using custom types for data would be optimal, but if you need to maintain DataTable approach, then it's simpler to format it before sending to UI.

Comment: I had hoped that it would automagically divide the cell into multiple cells, or expand the collection into a list.   I had converted to string earlier, but that leads to some issues if I need to later set up a context menu, or want to do something with a single value,  I supposed I can write functions to covert multiline strings to List and back, but seems... inelegant.